# how get values in controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

how can get the $new1 value from the given code

```
$heroprofile = $this->Profile->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Profile.Person_name' => $album, 'Profile.Category' => 'Movies')));

//$this->set('movies',$this->Moviemaster->find('all',array('conditions' => array($new => $album)))); 
$this->set('heroprofile', $heroprofile);

foreach ($heroprofile as $value) {
    $new1 = $value['Profile']['Person_type'];
    echo $new1;
}

$this->set('coll', $this->Moviemusic->find('all', array('fields' => array('DISTINCT(Moviemusic.type)'), 'conditions' => array($new1 => $album), 'limit' => 4, 'order' => 'rand()')));
```

Comment: you should do **print_r($heroprofile)**

Comment: what exactly you want here? or are you getting any error?

Comment: actually i need to get a value from $heroprofile .. and need to place that vale in the another query for the same page

Comment: You need to place that value by another value is it your question ? For example you have an id value 1, You want to save this value by replace another id value 10.Is it you question ?

Comment: as you are assigning new value for $new1 each time when loop will perform then how you will run query for all values of $value['Profile']['Person_type']. Your $new1 will overwrite each time in loop

Answer (score 2):

Try below code..

```
$heroprofile=$this->Profile->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Profile.Person_name' => $album,'Profile.Category' => 'Movies')));
$this->set('heroprofile',$heroprofile);
$newvalue = array();
foreach ($heroprofile as $value) {
     $new1=$value['Profile']['Person_type'];  
     $newvalue[]= $this->Moviemusic->find('all',array('fields' => array('DISTINCT(Moviemusic.type)'),'conditions'=>array($new1 => $album),'limit'=>4,'order'=>'rand()'));
}
$this->set('coll',$newvalue);

var_dump($newvalue);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right 
the select fail if you have no $new1 defined
try define default value before FOR

```
$heroprofile=$this->Profile->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Profile.Person_name' => $album,'Profile.Category' => 'Movies')));

                //$this->set('movies',$this->Moviemaster->find('all',array('conditions' => array($new => $album)))); 
                $this->set('heroprofile',$heroprofile);
$new1 = "some default person type";
foreach ($heroprofile as $value) {
                  $new1=$value['Profile']['Person_type'];  
                  echo $new1;
                }

            $this->set('coll',$this->Moviemusic->find('all',array('fields' => array('DISTINCT(Moviemusic.type)'),'conditions'=>array($new1 => $album),'limit'=>4,'order'=>'rand()')));
```

Answer (score 0):

By your comment if your question is how you will get same controller value for replace another value,You can try this format of code

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['Person_type'];
```

Now if you want to replace it by another value you can try like

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['Person_type']=1;
```

Here whatever you give in your field in person_type it will save 1.

Now if you want to replace this value by another model field you can try like

```
  $this->request->data['Profile']['Person_type']=$this->request->data['AnotherModel']['Another_field'];
```